# Prevent adding duplicate option on the select option of table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a data table similar as.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $("#example").DataTable({
            "order": [ 1, "asc" ],
            // "lengthMenu": [[ 100, 200, 500,-1], [ 100, 200, 500,'All']],
            "pageLength": -1,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": "false",
            "searchable": false,
            orderCellsTop: true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bInfo": false
        });
        
        $('.filterRow th').each( function (i) {
            var title = $(this).text();
            var select = $('<select><option value="">All</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var term = $(this).val();
                    table.column( i ).search(term, false, false ).draw();
                } );
            let includedArr = [];
            let colData = table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                if(d != ""){
                    d = d.replace("<del>","").replace("</del>","");
                    if( $.inArray(d, includedArr) < 0 ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
                        includedArr.push = d;
                    }
                }
            });
        } );
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>101</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>01</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>102</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>(20)</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>103</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>
            <del>10</del>
        </td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">Bldg</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Unit</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Floor</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Stack</th>
          <th colspan="2">
              Floor Level
          </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Floor 1</th>
          <th>Floor 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="filterRow">
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

You can run the code and check on the select option of `Floor 1` column, currently there it is showing double `10` option. But, it should have only one. Actually, there are this two options: `10` and '<del>10</del>'. Because of this `del` tag it considered as two options, however, I want to show just 10.

So, I tried by removing `<del>` tag but still, it is showing 3 options on the select field.

Comment: You aren't pushing to your `includedArr`. Try `includedArr.push(d);` instead of `includedArr.push = d;`

Comment: oh, my silly mistake. Thank you for pointing it.